# Getting ? and square box characters while converting binary data to text in java

Tags: java, binary, binaryfiles, data-conversion

I have a file containing the binary data and I'm using Java to convert the binary data to text but I'm getting question mark at few places in between. (these characters changes in every editor, like different char in eclipse and different in Intellij)

Sample Binary data - 00100000 11101110 10000000 10011110 01100101 01101110 00101100 00100000 01110100
For example the particular binary code (**11101110**) is not giving the correct character, using the below code for conversion

```
String raw = Arrays.stream(input.split(" "))
                .map(binary -> Integer.parseInt(binary, 2))
                .map(Character::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

I tried converting to UTF-8, ISO_8859_1 and other encoding schemes too but it didn't help.

Kindly help.

Comment: If you want to convert arbitiary binary data to readable characters, you may want to use Base64.

Comment: Where do you see that your character is not correct? If you display it in your console using a println it might just be the console that cannot display it. By default my console cannot display the ascii character 238 (11101110).

Comment: Charsets like UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1 have nothing to do with this.  You should not be using them at all.  For what it’s worth, the third and fourth values in your input (10000000 10011110, or 0x80 0x9e) are not printable characters.  Is this data supposed to be text, or just binary data?

Comment: All data is binary.  How it is to be interpreted is the issue.  What is its origin?  How do you know it isn't UTF-16 or some variant? Or little endian vs big endian?

Comment: I get these binary data from the images embedded into pdf file and I extract this data from those images and then convert it, if It is just console is not able to print it then can you please suggest about other options? The idea is to dump that readable characters into a txt file. please help

Comment: Your approach will not correctly extract text from most PDF documents.  Use a PDF parsing library.

Comment: "Ajay Sethi: *I get these binary data from the images embedded into pdf file ...*"  That is critical information and should have been part of the question.  Do what @VGR suggested.

Comment: @VGR I'm using PDF parsing library to extract binary data from pdf images and dumping all binary data into a txt file and reading from that txt file and converting, that's working fine, but  the binary code ( 11101110) is present in my pdf images around 28 times and the output file which I'm generating post conversion has also got 28 question marks symbol except these 28 junk characters, all binary code got converted fine. I'm suspecting while converting byte array into string is causing issue or eclipse console is not able to print the readable char (i'm running this program in windows)

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re doing.  You’re dumping binary data from images?  Why would you expect that data to represent readable characters?  Why is that data represented as binary digits (zeroes and ones)?  Where are you converting a byte array into a string, and why are you doing that?  It seems like you are doing a lot of steps that are part of your problem, but you left those steps out of your question.

Comment: Sorry I confused you but I didn't mention the all steps here because binary to text conversion is working fine except for the binary code as "11101110" , while I convert this binary code to text and print it in console, it gives question mark symbol in eclipse and even in txt file it shows the same.